# How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call to finish before it returns?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a  server side function that requires login. If the user is logged in the function will return 1 on success. If not, the function will return the login-page.

I want to call the function using Ajax and jQuery. What I do is submit the request with an ordinary link, with a click-function applied on it. If the user is not logged in or the function fails, I want the Ajax-call to return true, so that the href triggers.

However, when I use the following code, the function exits before the Ajax call is done.

How can I redirect the user gracefully to the loginpage?

```
$(".my_link").click(
    function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function(){
            return true;
        },
        success: function(msg){ 
            if (parseFloat(msg)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Might be an old thread, but as @kofifus points out setting async to false is a bad design and "no timeouts etc will be processed".  Might be try this simplified solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576418/6937841

Comment: You can change `return true;` to `window.location.href = url;` and it would gracefully redirect to the login page once ajax call is finished.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

If you don't want the `$.ajax()` function to return immediately, set the `async` option to `false`:

```
$(".my_link").click(
    function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        fail: function(){
            return true;
        },
        done: function(msg){ 
            if (parseFloat(msg)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But, I would note that this would be counter to the point of AJAX. Also, you should be handling the response in the `fail` and `done` functions. Those functions will only be called when the response is received from the server.

Comment: Passing along good practices, in my opinion, isn't judging, and is the mark of some of the best answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: **Never use `async: false`.** The browser's event loop will hang while waiting on unreliable network I/O. There's always a better way. In this case, the link's target can verify the user session and 302 to the login page.

Comment: For testing, `async: false` can be very useful.

Comment: Where have you been all my life?

Comment: @Matthew Really? What is the alternative to sending an ajax with async before sending user to other page or refreshing?

Comment: @NoBugs: always return false in click handler, and in success callback, navigate to where it should go.

Comment: `async` with value `false` is gone deprecated in most browser use cases. It may throw exceptions in newer version of browsers. See https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning (applies to `async` parameter of xhr `open` method, which is what uses jQuery).

Comment: @Frederic First of all`return false` is [not recommended](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), second, if you do preventDefault for browser click behavior, you have to handle such events for all links or code that does a page-navigation. (and waiting some amount of time while the pre-leave-page-ajax runs is basically the same problem @Matthew is talking about. If the ajax never finishes it would not go to the other page.

Comment: @NoBugs, yes I know about `return false` being not the best practice in a jQuery event context, but I was just sticking to what the op was practicing himself. In short, I do not think this is the point here. And yes, what the op want to do has the drawbacks you state, it is not specific to what I have suggested.

Comment: Note that async: false doesn't support cross-domain and jsonp requests.

Comment: @Matthew after a discussion with our tech lead I tend to agree with his recommendation to revise your statement slightly.  **Almost  never use `async: false`**.  There are always edge cases where doing this could make sense.

Comment: How is this a good answer? Not using async=false makes sense, however, there doesn't seem to be an alternative answer. How DO you WAIT for an async ajax call to finish?

Comment: The real answer is where he says: _Also, you should be handling the response in the error and success functions._

Comment: Ah nice to know :p evergreen submit, cgp  !

Comment: 'done' hasn't worked for me, I've used `success: function(msg,status,jqXHR)` instead and worked

Comment: This answer was prob good 12 years ago. However is 2021 this DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 48):

I am not using `$.ajax` but the `$.post` and `$.get` functions, so if I need to wait for the response, I use this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
$.get("...");
```

Answer (score 38):

The underlying XMLHttpRequest object (used by jQuery to make the request) supports the
asynchronous property. Set it to **false**. Like

```
async: false
```

Answer (score 29):

Instead of setting async to false which is usually bad design, you may want to consider blocking the UI while the operation is pending.

This can be nicely achieved with jQuery promises as follows:

```
// same as $.ajax but settings can have a maskUI property
// if settings.maskUI==true, the UI will be blocked while ajax in progress
// if settings.maskUI is other than true, it's value will be used as the color value while bloking (i.e settings.maskUI='rgba(176,176,176,0.7)'
// in addition an hourglass is displayed while ajax in progress
function ajaxMaskUI(settings) {
    function maskPageOn(color) { // color can be ie. 'rgba(176,176,176,0.7)' or 'transparent'
        var div = $('#maskPageDiv');
        if (div.length === 0) {
            $(document.body).append('<div id="maskPageDiv" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;display:none"></div>'); // create it
            div = $('#maskPageDiv');
        }
        if (div.length !== 0) {
            div[0].style.zIndex = 2147483647;
            div[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
            div[0].style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }
    function maskPageOff() {
        var div = $('#maskPageDiv');
        if (div.length !== 0) {
            div[0].style.display = 'none';
            div[0].style.zIndex = 'auto';
        }
    }
    function hourglassOn() {
        if ($('style:contains("html.hourGlass")').length < 1) $('<style>').text('html.hourGlass, html.hourGlass * { cursor: wait !important; }').appendTo('head');
        $('html').addClass('hourGlass');
    }
    function hourglassOff() {
        $('html').removeClass('hourGlass');
    }

    if (settings.maskUI===true) settings.maskUI='transparent';

    if (!!settings.maskUI) {
        maskPageOn(settings.maskUI);
        hourglassOn();
    }

    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(settings)
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (!!settings.maskUI) {
                maskPageOff();
                hourglassOff();
            }
            dfd.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (!!settings.maskUI) {
                maskPageOff();
                hourglassOff();
            }
            dfd.resolve(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

with this you can now do:

```
ajaxMaskUI({
    url: url,
    maskUI: true // or try for example 'rgba(176,176,176,0.7)'
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error ' + textStatus);
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('success ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

And the UI will block until the ajax command returns

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b69ubLa0/21/)

Comment: Doesn't setting async to false do the exact same thing except in a single line of code?

Comment: Not at all. Setting async to false make the request async - that is halts processing until it returns which is usually bad practice, for example no events, other ajax requests, timeouts etc will be processed. You can also modify the code above to block only part of the UI while your ajax is processing (ie the part it will affect)

Answer (score 16):

In modern JS you can simply use `async`/`await`, like:

```
  async function upload() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: 30000,
            success: (response) => {
                resolve(response);
            },
            error: (response) => {
                reject(response);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Then call it in an `async` function like:

```
let response = await upload();
```

Answer (score 14):

I think things would be easier if you code your `success` function to load the appropriate page instead of returning `true` or `false`.

For example instead of returning `true` you could do:

```
window.location="appropriate page";
```

That way when the success function is called the page gets redirected.

Answer (score 7):

Since I don't see it mentioned here I thought I'd also point out that the jQuery [when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) statement can be very useful for this purpose.

Their example looks like this:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

The "then" part won't execute until the "when" part finishes.

Comment: Can I also nest these multiple times?  _(I am glad you added this option; I could not wrap my head around any of the other suggestions. This finally made sense.)_

Answer (score 5):

since async ajax is deprecated try using nested async functions with a Promise. There may be syntax errors.

```
async function fetch_my_data(_url, _dat) {

   async function promised_fetch(_url, _dat) {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         $.ajax({
            url:  _url,
            data: _dat,
            type: 'POST',
            success: (response) => {
               resolve(JSON.parse(response));
            },
            error: (response) => {
               reject(response);
            }
         });
      });
   }

   var _data = await promised_fetch(_url, _dat);
   
   return _data;
}

var _my_data = fetch_my_data('server.php', 'get_my_data=1');
```

Answer (score 2):

It should wait until get request completed. After that I'll return get request body from where function is called.

```
function foo() {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
    });
    return JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);  
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: Added @Dropout.

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Ejaz! Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was at today's date asked 12 years ago and was 'How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call to finish before it returns?' jQuery has come a long way since then.

There are a few solutions mentioned above and I couldn't get any of them to work with the latest version of jQuery:  $.when().then.() doesn't seem to be synchronous unless its uses 'async: false' which is no longer supported, so doesn't work in newer versions of jQuery.

But promises are built into jQuery ajax calls so it shouldn't be that difficult to make ajax calls synchronous.

I use namespaced js functions so the example below is in that format. The example is for custom form validation that calls the server to validate that user input does not attempt to duplicate an existing item.

This code will probably not work in IE or Legacy Edge unless using Babel, but I tend to block those browsers as they are no longer supported by Microsoft.

```
///Namespace validate
check: async function(settings){
    let IsValid = false;
    let Message = ''
    let data = await validate.serverCheck('function', value);
    IsValid = data.OK;
    Message = data.Message;
}

serverCheck: async function (fn, value) {
    var request = {
        validateValue: $.sanitize(value)
    };

    let result;

    try {
            result = await $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: "/api/validate/" + fn + "/",
                data: request
        });

        return result;
    } catch (x) {}
}
```

and there you have it