# jQuery getting just added by ajax element

Tags: jquery

```
$.post('includes/script.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
});

alert ($('#new').length)
```

php script is `<php echo "<div id="new">text</div>" ?>`

it alerts 0, so it can't see new div.

How can you make it see new div?

Comment: my bad, too simplified it. corrected.

Comment: found it. async: false.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns

Comment: @Quio if you can move your code in to the success handler it will work for you.  Javascript is an event drivin language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait till your post is done before you can check the length.  Do something like this:

```
$.post('includes/script.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    var newItem = $(data).appendTo('body');
    alert (newItem.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling it?  I get alert 1 in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  Note that "function" was misspelled in your code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
addnew();
});

function addnew (){
    $('body').append('<div id="new">text</div>');
    alert ($('#new').length)
}
</script>
```