# jQuery: a function containing an ajax() function won't return ajax() response

Tags: jquery

In an attempt to make my jQuery code modular, i.e. reusable, I've placed an ajax() function inside of another function `fetch_ajax()`. I'm trying to call `fetch_ajax()` with parameters from other places, which *should* simply run the contained `ajax()` and return the response.

But that's not happening - instead, `fetch_ajax()` apparently returns false too quickly to the caller and doesn't wait until `ajax()` has completed the request and gotten a response.

Here's the code:

The `fetch_ajax()` function

```
function fetch_ajax(url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  });
}
```

The calling function:

```
function caller() {
  response = fetch_ajax('script.php');
  alert(response); //this is always 'undefined'
}
```

In `fetch_ajax()`, I've tried not directly returning `response` from within `ajax()`, but writing it to a variable, and returning that variable after `ajax()` - that didn't work either (same result).

When I place a 2nd alert right before `return response;` inside of the `ajax()` function, I'm seeing that one fire AFTER the one inside `caller()`. So I'm thinking that somehow, `fetch_ajax()` doesn't wait for the contained function to execute before it returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your train of thought is wrong - the `.ajax()` function is written to not wait for the contained function. `success` is an event listener, so it is fired dynamically whenever the response arrives. You could use synchronous requests or jQuery queues to solve this, but both have disadvantages.

See [How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call to finish before it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns) for the synchronous request solution. It's much simpler than the other one, but will hang your browser if the server dies right then or a hyperactive firewall blocks the answer or an angry lolcat eats your request on the way.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's the explanation I needed. I think the best way for me right now would be to rewrite `fetch_ajax()` to something like `output_ajax()`, if you catch my drift. With a handful more params passed to this new function, it should also be capable of accounting for teh lolcats :) Thanks.