# setting a jquery ajax request to async = false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm attempting to get started with google wallet and am generating a jwt token via an ajax request.

When a user hits the purchase button it fires the purchase() function which in turn sends off some data to get the jwt using the get_jwt_token_for_user() function. I've set the ajax request to not be asynchronous to ensure that the jwt is sent to the google payments handler.

However the purchase() function seems to continue before the jwt is returned by the get_jwt_token_for_user() function. The log output shows that the numbers 1 and 2 are printed to console before the jwt is printed to the console from the get_jwt_token_for_user() function.

```
function get_jwt_token_for_user(the_key)
{
    var JwtTokenURL = "/get_jwt_token";
    var the_user_name = $('#user_name').val();
    var the_user_email = $('#user_email').val();
    var the_user_number = $('#user_number').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "Get",
        url: JwtTokenURL,
        data: {user_number : the_user_number, user_name : the_user_name, user_email : the_user_email, the_d_key : the_key},
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var myObject = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(myObject.jwt_token);
            return myObject.jwt_token
        },
        failure: function(fail){ alert(fail); }
     });
}

function purchase(the_key)
{
    console.log("1");
    var jwt_token = get_jwt_token_for_user(the_key);
    console.log("2");
    if (jwt_token !== "")
    {
        console.log(jwt_token);
        goog.payments.inapp.buy({
            parameters: {},
            'jwt'     : jwt_token,
            'success' : successHandler,
            'failure' : failureHandler
          });
    }
}
```

Any idea what I can do to ensure that the ajax request has returned the data before the purchase() function marches on without the jwt value?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the async problem, but your return statement won't do any good in the success handler.  I think you want it after the $.ajax() call has finished, so put it after that. Otherwise your get_jwt_token_for_user() function will always return null.

Comment: resructure your code so the code you want to get executed go into the callback ;)

Comment: Bit confused - nothing in the code you posted actually calls the `purchase` function from what I can see, i.e. there are no invocations of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `get_jwt_token_for_user` function doesn't return anything, you need something more like this:

```
function get_jwt_token_for_user(the_key) {
    //...
    var myObject;
    $.ajax({ 
        //...
        success: function(result) {
            myObject = JSON.parse(result);
        },
        //...
     });
     return myObject ? myObject.jwt_token : '';
}
```

Returning something from your `success` callback doesn't cause that value to be returned by `$.ajax` and JavaScript functions **do not** return the value of their last expressions, you **must** include an explicit `return` if you want your function to return something.

You should also stop using `async:false` as soon as possible, it is rather user-hostile and [it is going away](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11013). Your code should look more like this:

```
function get_jwt_token_for_user(the_key, callback) {
    //...
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "Get",
        url: JwtTokenURL,
        data: {user_number : the_user_number, user_name : the_user_name, user_email : the_user_email, the_d_key : the_key},
        success: function(result) {
            var myObject = JSON.parse(result);
            callback(myObject.jwt_token);
        },
        failure: function(fail){ alert(fail); }
     });
}

function purchase(the_key) {
    get_jwt_token_for_user(the_key, function(jwt_token) {
        if (jwt_token !== "") {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible using `function(){ $.ajax({...})}`, wrapping the ajax with an anonymous function ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: No `return` statement means no return value and [`$.ajax` always returns a `jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns) accepted answer ?

Comment: Awesome dude - solved the issue perfectly. I'll also take your advice on the async = false tip.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: (1) That answer is ancient and the jQuery interface has changed. (2) The return value of the `success` handler in that question and answer will be ignored. (3) That anonymous click handler function doesn't return anything.