# Jquery plugin blockUI not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, blockui, jquery-blockui

I want to block the current page when a specific ajax call is made and use a blockUI as a message box. I can't just use `$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);`

My code is the following..

```
bc.find('.submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('lock'))
        return;
    $.blockUI();
    $(this).addClass('lock');
    bc.submit();
});

var validator;
validator = bc.validate({
    ignore: '',
    rules: {
        UserName: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        UserName: 'must have',
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/yyyy/xxxx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: postdata,
            complete: function () {
                bc.find('.submit').removeClass('lock');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'OK') {
                    $.blockUI({ message: 'OK' });
                    ......
                }
                else {
                    switch (data.status) {
                        case 'xxx':
                        ......
                    }
                    $.unblockUI();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
                alert('xxx');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The scenario is that when I click the `.submit` button, the page is blocked and a ajax call is made to the server to get a data response. When the ajax call is successful, I unblock the current page and if data.status is 'OK', I show a message box (also based on blockUI plugin). Else I show an error on the current page, and then unblock it.

**Edit at 2016, there is a edit which change the question meaning(maybe due to my very poor English at that moment), I have rolled change back here, and make it more clear, please do not change below again.**

But in fact, ***only after ajax call is completed*** (debug step over the code in `ajax complete handler`), then see:

1. first `$.blockUI();` excuted
2. execute `$.blockUI({ message: 'OK' })` or not
3. then `$.unblockUI()` be called

(Above is what I mean abnormal execution sequence of chrome or firefox debug tool in the answer.because `blockui code` should not be executed after ajax complete)

It's not what I want, and I can't figure this out.

Comment: You can greatly simplify your code by using ajaxBlockUI
see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28358070/460084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an execution sequence anomaly caused by browser's debug tools in both chrome and firefox. With the debugger, I confirmed whether `$.blockUI()` executed before the ajax call or not. It was always executing after I stepped over the complete handler in ajax. Just now, I set a breakpoint in server side code and I found that execution sequence becomes normal as I want it be!

**update at 2016-01-25:**

**Note:**

1. This answer is answered at 2012-09-26. I don't know whether chrome or firefox still has something `abnormal execution sequence` when doing a `async call` now.(But I remember, at that time, set `a break point` on the line - `$.blockUI({ message: 'OK' });` in chrome debug tool, type `F10`(go next) , would see chrome just step over the break point, and nothing heppen)
2. Actually there is no error in the question's code. I think why I ask this question is only because I see the abnormal execution sequence in debug tool, which make me confuse, and the answer is here. If you want to find out why your code not work or something else , you'd better to find other answers or ask a new question.
3. About `abnormal execution sequence`, now, I think maybe it is by `blockui` too. Because we don't see how `$.blockUI()` worked, maybe `block element function` is stored deep inside the chrome execution callback stack. I may place the breakpoint at wrong line If that assumption is true(so maybe need set breakpoint in `blockui source code`)

And, I haven't work with `blockui` for many years.If you just want a block message box, I suggest [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a way that the message showing during the ajax call?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue because i used sync ajax call that is aync is false

I solved it by making an ajax call async to true

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async :true});
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the Block UI in the beforeSend function and the unBlockUI in the complete function so that you get the behavior you are expecting.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/yyyy/xxxx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: postdata,
            beforeSend : function() {
               $.blockUI({ message: 'OK' });
            }, 
            complete: function () {
                bc.find('.submit').removeClass('lock');
                 $.unblockUI();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'OK') {

                    ......
                }
                else {
                    switch (data.status) {
                        case 'xxx':
                        ......
                    }

                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
                alert('xxx');
            }
        });
```

This will make sure your Ui will block as soon as the request is sent and unblock as soon as its completed..

Comment: I add $.blockUI() to beforeSend，but it doesn't work.In my question,I even put the $.blockUI() before submit event...It's so strange.

Comment: I got the same problem, do you find any answer?

Comment: In my situation,this execution sequence anomaly caused by browser's debug tools,both chrome and firefox.
Because I used debug tool to confirm whether $.blockUI() excuted before ajax call,but it always excuted after stepping over the complete handler of ajax.When I set a breakpoint in server side code ,then I found execution sequence become normal as I want it be!

Comment: I was able to get this working but I had to make sure that the async was set to true.

Comment: @fassetar.. If you set `asyn:true` then it is a bad sign. You are defeating the very purpose of `AJAX`

Comment: @Sushanth-- I agree, however setting the asyn to true does no harm by default that is its value. Which I think you knew, but more to my case I was doing multiple ajax calls where the first needed to be returned before the second could be called and depended on the results from the first.

Comment: @fassetar.. Then use the concept of defer and promise, or pass the function as a callback to the success handler if there is dependency between multiple ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your code much simpler with a wrapper around ajax such as ajaxBlockUI - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358070/460084

all you'll have to do is add blockUI:true to ajaxBlockUI and the actual blocking and unblocking the UI will be handled internally.