# Checking if user exists jquery validator,ajax and codeigneter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I m trying to check if a username exists or not but even if the username doesn't exists it keeps saying "Username already exists" this is my javascript code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkUsername", 
    function(value, element) {
        var test = "";
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: site_url + "/ajax/checkusername/" + value,
            success: function(result){
               if(result=="exists")
                   return false;
               else
                   return true;
            }
        });
    }, 
    "Username Already Exists."
);



    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            username2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                checkUsername:true
            },
            password2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function checkusername($username)
{
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $user = $this->user_model->getUser($username);
            if($user == null)
            {
                echo json_encode("notexists");
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode("exists");
            }  
}
```

Any Ideas about this how this can be solved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the very end of your JavaScript, you have an extra `});`.  Copy & paste typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you encoding the response as JSON when you're not parsing JSON with your `ajax`?

What happens when you simply do this?:

```
public function checkusername($username)
{
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user = $this->user_model->getUser($username);
        if($user == null)
        {
            echo "notexists";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "exists";
        }  
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkUsername", 
    function(value, element) {
        var result = false;
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            async: false,
            url: site_url + "/ajax/checkusername/" + value,
            success: function(msg) {
                result = (msg == "exists") ? false : true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }, 
    "Username Already Exists."
);
```

Comment: Tried it still same problem

Comment: @Trustos, I'm doing nearly the exact same thing with my CodeIgniter & `ajax` and it's working fine for me.  The only difference is that mine is using `type = "post"`.  Do a console log in your `ajax` to see what the response looks like.  Add `console.log(result);` as the first line inside your `success` callback function.  Then look at your JavaScript console to see the exact value being returned.

Comment: It returns exist and notexist the values it should. Its like the error message Username already exists just keeps on popping up when it shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` read a string. Cause you do `echo json_encode` this string is json.

You can use `$.getJSON` in stead of `$.ajax`

```
$.getJSON( site_url + "/ajax/checkusername/" + value, function( json ) {
  if(json=="notexists"){alert('Not exists')}
 });
```

or add `$.parseJSON` to your original code:

```
  if($.parseJSON(result)=="exists")
```

**update:** i had to change my answer
your function doesn't return the result of your `$.ajax`. `$.ajax` had to set your return value. Cause can't return before your ajax has been finished, you also have to add `async: false` to your request (see: [How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call to finish before it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns))

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkUsername", 
    function(value, element) {
        var test = false;
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        url: site_url + "/ajax/checkusername/" + value,
        success: function(result){
           if(result=="notexists") {test = true; }       
           }
    });
    return test;
    }, 
    "Username Already Exists."
);
```

Comment: what is the result when you load site_url + "/ajax/checkusername/" + value in a browser?

Comment: If I do this one
http://localhost/virtualclubmanager/index.php/ajax/checkusername/aaaaaaa
it returns "nonexists" because its not in database
If I do this one
http://localhost/virtualclubmanager/index.php/ajax/checkusername/testing
It returns "exists" because it is in the database