# Run script when select from selectpicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me. I have a form, which has the class `selectpicker`.
I need to run the JS every time when a user selects any value in `.selectpicker`. Is that possible? Is there any method?

I have the following script for on load:

```
  $(window).on('load', function () {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      'selectedText': 'cat'
    });

  // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('hide');
  });
```

But I also need to do this with the select value in the form `.selectpicker`.

```
        <div class="field field-manufacture">
          <label>Výrobce</label>
          <select n:name=manufacturer class="selectpicker" data-style="btn">
          </select>
        </div><!-- /.field -->

        <div n:snippet=searchSnippet class="field field-model">
          <label>Model</label>
          <select n:name=model class="selectpicker" data-style="btn">
          </select>
        </div><!-- /.field -->
```

Snippet is dependent on first manufacturer, so when I select from the first, the second selectpicker is reloading data from database and changing CSS styling - so I need to run the first script again.

Version of jquery: 1.10.2

Thank you!

-- edit, added AJAX:

```
        <script>
           {include #jsCallback, input => manufacturer, link => firstChange}
        </script>


        {define #jsCallback}

        $('#{$control["searchForm"][$input]->htmlId}').on('change', function() {
        $.nette.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{link {$link}!}',
            data: {
                'value': $(this).val(),
            }
        });
        });

        {/define}
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select').change(function(){
    // logic goes here

    var value = $(this).val();

});
```

Comment: How does the html of your select look, and what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Paste this `$('.selectpicker').change(function(){ alert(1); });` after `$(window).on('load', function () {`. Refresh the page and change the select and see if anything pops up.

Comment: Yes, I can see popup with value "1"

Comment: That means it works. So instead of `alert(1);` put the script you want to run everytime a user selects something.

Comment: But when I put script, nothing happens - It is maybe because of AJAX delay to load data into second select. Is possible to wait until data is loaded? Thank you

Comment: I can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns) that I can use: async: false (it works) but there is comment to **Never use** async: false