# jquery wait on response

Tags: jquery, ajax

It's been awhile since I worked with query and I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't waiting on the response. I looked for answers similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755913). I must be missing something pretty simple.

The calling function:

```
$('#cappuccino-button').click(function () {
    $('#screen-one').hide();    
    var hasMilk = IsThereMilk();
    if (hasMilk) {
        $('#cappuccino-success').show();
    } else {
        $('#milk-fail').show();
    }
}
```

The function itself:

```
function IsThereMilk() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://milkstore/gotany',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log('*****AJAX' + data.hasMilk);
            return data.hasMilk;
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me identify why my calling function isn't waiting on the ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsThereMilk()` call does not actually return a value. Though if `$.ajax()` was returned the value would be a jQuery promise object, not a `Boolean`.

Try adjusting `js`, to `return` `$.ajax()` from `IsThereMilk()` call, `.then()` to check if response `data.hasMilk`

```
function IsThereMilk() {
    return $.ajax("http://milkstore/gotany");
}

$("#cappuccino-button").click(function () {
    $("#screen-one").hide();    
    var hasMilk = IsThereMilk();
    hasMilk.then(function(data) {
      if (data.hasMilk) {
        $("#cappuccino-success").show();
       } else {
        $("#milk-fail").show();
       }
    })
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r8hc6nna/

Comment: would the `return data.hasMilk;` not work for the return?

Comment: @JonHarding _"would the return data.hasMilk; not work for the return?"_ No, not as a value returned from within `$,ajax()` that would be returned from `IsThereMilk`. `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, `$.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object which can be accessed at `.then()`, `.done()`, `.always()`, `.fail()`

Comment: when returning $.ajax do you not need to include the success / fail properties?

Comment: @JonHarding No, you can use `.then()`, `.done()` to handle resolved promise, `.always()` to handle both resolved or rejected promises, `.fail()` to handle rejected promise. See updated post, https://jsfiddle.net/r8hc6nna/

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to move the condition hasMilk in ajax success?

```
function IsThereMilk() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://milkstore/gotany',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log('*****AJAX' + data.hasMilk);
            if (data.hasMilk) {
               $('#cappuccino-success').show();
            } else {
               $('#milk-fail').show();
            }
        }
    });
}

$('#cappuccino-button').click(function () {
    $('#screen-one').hide();    
    IsThereMilk();
}
```

Comment: no the milk function needs to be reused by multiple functions

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `when` can be used to achieve similar results.
This is first piece of code that I've written that uses `when`

```
$.when( loadMoreComms() ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                        {#var comsect = $('#comment-box-section');#}
                        $('.loader').css('display', 'none');
                    });
```

and this is my loadmoreComms()

```
function loadMoreComms() {
            return $.ajax({*put you ajax code here*});
}
```

Read more about jquery `when` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)