# Download CSV file to the client

Tags: python, csv, flask, download

I have the following route:

```
@app.route('/download/', methods=['GET'])
def download():
    output_filename = request.args.get('output_filename')
    data = dict(foos=[1,2,3,3,2,1], bars=[7,7,7,7,7,7])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    result = df.to_csv(index=False)
    response = make_response(result)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={output_filename}'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/csv'
    return response
```

which I'm calling with AJAX as follows:

```
function download(data, handler = null) {
  let data = {output_filename: "foo.csv"};
  let url = "/download/";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
  });
}
```

However, **nothing's appearing on the client side.** Am I missing something here?

Comment: if def download(): was just a return with data do you get anything?

Comment: yep -- thinking i'm a bit of a noob here. `success: ...` returns the CSV data, so thinking https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545311/5058116 might have the answer ...

Comment: I upvoted you question as i think it's a great one. A lot of documentation seems to forget about the case where you may actually need to get your data back before the function finishes.

Comment: @oppressionslayer I am getting the data in the `success` closure as a CSV string but I wonder why it didn't write it to a file

Comment: i can't get the function to work in node, is there a better cli/ide to test your ajax call in? I'm really trying to solve this one, as i had the same issue using node which i fixed and am interested in this one. so i'm really wondering what your using to run your javascript

Comment: If you want browser to interpret content-disposition headers and etc make it a direct get request to server not the ajax. Create html <a> element with download url and trigger click event on it.

Answer (score 0):

Im more familiar with node than ajax ( i had the same issue in nodejs which i fixed here on stackoverflow), but maybe this will help:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
```

from [How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call to finish before it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns)